# gallery last image fix

Tags: actionscript-3

I almost have this thing the way I want it except when I'm clicking forward or backwards through my images, once it hits the array length, the next images doesn't show. It is only an issue when I add the checkImage() method. Anyone see what I have wrong?

fix**

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;


    import com.greensock.TweenMax;
    import com.greensock.layout.*;
    import com.greensock.loading.LoaderMax;
    import com.greensock.loading.XMLLoader;
    import com.greensock.loading.ImageLoader;
    import com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent;
    import com.greensock.loading.display.ContentDisplay;
    import com.greensock.loading.data.XMLLoaderVars;


    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {

        public var imgHolder:MovieClip;

        private var ls:LiquidStage;
        private var la:LiquidArea;
        private var xml:XMLLoader;
        private var index:int = 0;
        private var images:Array;


        public function Main()
        {
            arrowRight.alpha = arrowLeft.alpha = .5;
            xmlLoader();
        }

        private function xmlLoader():void
        {
            LoaderMax.activate([ImageLoader]);
            xml = new XMLLoader("assets/data.xml", new XMLLoaderVars()
                                                    .name("loader")
                                                    .estimatedBytes(600000)
                                                    .onComplete(xmlLoaded)
                                                    .onProgress(loadProgress));
            xml.load();

        }

        private function xmlLoaded(e:LoaderEvent):void
        {
            trace("Loaded");
            arrowListeners();
            showImage(index);
        }

        private function loadProgress(event:LoaderEvent):void
        {
            progressMC.progressBar.scaleX = event.target.progress;
        }

        private function showImage(index:int):void

        {
            ls = new LiquidStage(this.stage, 1024, 768, 1024, 768);
            la = new LiquidArea(imgHolder, 0, 0, 1024, 768);

            images = LoaderMax.getContent("loader"); 

            imgHolder.addChild(images[index]);

            TweenMax.from(images[index], 1, {alpha:0});
            la.attach(images[index], {scaleMode:ScaleMode.PROPORTIONAL_OUTSIDE, crop:true});


        }

        // BUTTON FUNCTIONS
        private function arrowListeners():void
        {
            arrowRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollOverArrowHandler, false, 0, true);
            arrowRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rollOutArrowHandler, false, 0, true);
            arrowRight.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, showNext );
            arrowLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollOverArrowHandler, false, 0, true);
            arrowLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rollOutArrowHandler, false, 0, true);
            arrowLeft.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, showPrev );
        }

        private function rollOverArrowHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            TweenMax.to(e.currentTarget, 0.5, {alpha:1});
        }

        private function rollOutArrowHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            TweenMax.to(e.currentTarget, 0.5, {alpha:.5});
        }

        // CLICK LISTENERS
        private function showNext( e:MouseEvent ):void
        {
            index++
            if (index > images.length - 1) 
            {
                index = 0;
            }

            showImage(index);
        }

        private function showPrev( e:MouseEvent ):void
        {
            index--
            if (index < 0) 
            {
                index = images.length - 1;
            }
            showImage(index);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things come to mind:

1) index is a global variable and a function param - conflicting?

2) in the checkimage function you pass in 'index' but refer to 0 in getChildAt and RemoveChildAt

3) you don't call showimage in checkimage if the numchildren > 0 is true

I'd want to trace into all of this to sort it out.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to add different vars to fix the param confliction and the rest of your issue list but now getting an error "TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Shape@4e18aa11 to flash.display.Sprite." I don't know any other way to get rid of the old image with what I got. Can you think of another safe way to remove the previous image?

Comment: Not entirely sure what the code is supposed to be doing.. but I'd wonder if you could just load all the images at the start and loop over them. Why is it loading and then reloading them?

Comment: Oh yea Im new to this so my code might look shaky. Im just trying to set up next and prev buttons for images gallery with browser scaling. I think initially I had it looping without the checkImage function and it worked fine, but I figured there needed to be some type of garbage collection. Should I remove checkImage()?

Comment: GC is automatic in Flex. As long as you are careful not to grow the array each time (IE just loop over the # of known values) you'll be fine. If its expensive to preload the images then maybe this is a better approach.. otherwise "the easy way is hard enough".

Comment: Ok the above code is what I have now and it worked fine. No problems, so I hope with this the GC is still in automatic flex. Thnaks.